# How to create zip64 archive using shutil.make_archive

Tags: python, zip, 64-bit

Python code snippet which creates creates zip archive file from a folder.

```python
shutil.make_archive(file_path, 'zip', folder_path)
```

I am getting this error :

> Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions.

How to create ZIP64 archive file using `shutil.make_archive`?

Note: I cannot use `zipfile.ZipFile` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using a Python version prior to 3.4 
unfortunately after reading shutil source code on github [github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py) . it's clearly using zipfile.ZipFile from zipfile this is a closed issue now see here [python](https://bugs.python.org/issue17189), so Starting from Python 3.4, ZIP64 extensions is availble by default .
But Prior to Python 3.4, make_archive will not create a file with ZIP64 extensions.
If you are using an older version of Python and want ZIP64, you can use the  zipfile.ZipFile() directly which you already mentioned .